# Is there a way in Leaflet to reset the function from a L.easybutton?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, layer

Using Leaflet, I linked to a L.easyButton a function which adds a geoJson polygon layer to a map, and that activates different functions "onEachFeature" of this layer. Among them, a function when clicking on a feature which creates a separate geoJson polygon layer with this feature and add it to a specific LayerGroup. What I would like is that after clicking on a feature, the different functions "onEachFeature" would not be activated anymore and that the user would need to push the L.easyButton again if he/she wants to do that another time. Everything works fine, except the fact to deactivate the "onEachFeature" functions. I tried to use `map.removeControl(`), `map.removeLayer()` and delete the variable directly, but none of these options work.

My code is:

```
L.easyButton( '<strong>Sélectionner une commune</strong>', function(){
    var communes_geojson = $.getJSON("data/Adm/Adm_Communes_4326.geojson",function(communes){
        var communes_new = L.geoJson(communes, {
            style:  stylelayer.communes,    
            onEachFeature: function addMyData (feature,layer){
                layer.on({
                    click: selectcommune
                });
            }
        });
        map.addControl(communes_new);
    });
    info.addTo(map);
},
{position: 'topright'}).addTo(map);

function selectcommune(e) {
    var layer=e.target;
    var feature = e.target.feature;
    var selectcommune1 = L.geoJson(feature, {
        style:  stylelayer.highlight
    }).addTo(map);

    control_map2.addOverlay({
        name:feature.properties.NameFRE,
        layer:selectcommune1
    });
    
    // don't work
    
    // map.removeControl(communes_geojson);
    // map.removeControl(communes_new);
    // map.removeControl(layer);
    
    // map.removeLayer(communes_geojson);
    // map.removeLayer(communes_new);
    // map.removeLayer(layer);  
    
    // delete communes_geojson;
    // delete communes_new;
    // delete layer;
```

Tahnk you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In `selectcommune`, once you do what you want (style your feature and add your overlay), you then need to go back and void out the `onEachFeature` function that you had added with the L.easyButton:

```js
L.easyButton( '<strong>Sélectionner une commune</strong>', function(){
    var communes_geojson = $.getJSON("data/Adm/Adm_Communes_4326.geojson",function(communes){
        var communes_new = L.geoJson(communes, {
            style:  stylelayer.communes,    
            onEachFeature: function addMyData (feature,layer){
                layer.on({
                    click: e => selectcommune(e, communes_new)
                });
            }
        });
        map.addControl(communes_new);
    });
    info.addTo(map);
},


function selectcommune(e, data) {
    var layer=e.target;
    var feature = e.target.feature;
    var selectcommune1 = L.geoJson(feature, {
        style:  stylelayer.highlight
    }).addTo(map);

    control_map2.addOverlay({
        name:feature.properties.NameFRE,
        layer:selectcommune1
    });

    data.eachLayer( layer => layer.on = () => {} )
}
```

So you hit the easybutton, and `layer.on` is set for each feature to fire the `selectcommune`.  When it fires, it removes the `layer.on` function (or overwrites it to do nothing), until you hit the easybutton again.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. This solution does not work on my side, because of the following error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: communes is not defined". Do you know why?

Comment: My bad, of course its not defined.  Better to pass `communes_new` as a parameter to `selectcommune`.  Then you can call `eachFeature` and void out the function.  I had to do some digging in the leaflet docs to track this down, but I havne't tested it.  If you create a reproducible example on codepen or codesandbox, I can fork it and make sure it works.  Basically, an L.geoJson inherits from L.FeatureGroup which inherits from L.LayerGroup, so `eachLayer` should be available to use on your `communes_new`